# Como manter a contagem regressiva rodando em background

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Estou tentando fazer uma contagem regressiva de 24 horas porem que se mantenha rodando em background, pois quero enviar uma notificação quando estiver faltando 5 horas, oque consegui até agora foi tentar implementar um service com broacast receiver ( não entendi muito bem esse ), porem toda vez que o app é fechado ( deletado dos recentes ) a contagem para e reinicia quando abro o app.

MainActivity:

```
    package br.com.igoroliv.testecountdown;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "igr";
    private TextView txvcon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txvcon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txv_tempo);
        startService(new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class));
        Log.i(TAG, "Started service");
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateGUI(intent); // or whatever method used to update your GUI fields
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(BroadcastService.COUNTDOWN_BR));
        Log.i(TAG, "Registered broacast receiver");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(br);
        Log.i(TAG, "Unregistered broacast receiver");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(br);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Receiver was probably already stopped in onPause()
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //stopService(new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class));
        //Log.i(TAG, "Stopped service");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void updateGUI(Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            long millisUntilFinished = intent.getLongExtra("countdown", 0);
            Log.i(TAG, "Countdown seconds remaining: " +  millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            txvcon.setText(""+millisUntilFinished/1000);
        }
    }
}
```

BroadcastService

```
package br.com.igoroliv.testecountdown;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by igord on 19/08/2017.
 */

public class BroadcastService  extends Service {

    private final static String TAG = "BroadcastService";

    public static final String COUNTDOWN_BR = "br.com.igoroliv.countdown_br";
    Intent bi = new Intent(COUNTDOWN_BR);

    CountDownTimer cdt = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.i(TAG, "Starting timer...");

        cdt = new CountDownTimer(80000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                Log.i(TAG, "Countdown seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                bi.putExtra("countdown", millisUntilFinished);
                sendBroadcast(bi);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.i(TAG, "Timer finished");
            }
        };

        cdt.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        //cdt.cancel();
        //Log.i(TAG, "Timer cancelled");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tem de por isso no seu manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="SeuBroadcastReceiver"
android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
<intent-filter> 
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

fazendo isso, o seu serviço vai rodar eternamente, digamos assim.

Comment: Eu não tenho uma classe Broadcastreceiver entao nao funciona

Comment: veja aqui: http://blog.globalcode.com.br/2010/05/respondendo-eventos-no-android.html

Comment: Não entendi oque tu me passou, eu quero ter 24 horas contando na minha tela, porem quando  o app abrir novamente ele continuar contando da onde parou, não reiniciar a contagem

Comment: voce precisa ter um broadcastreceiver para poder receber as msgs do serviço, pois pelo que postou, voce precisa quer o contador reinicie a partir de onde parou quando a aplicação foi fechada, dai voce vai ter de implementar um para poder ativar os flags no manifest para o serivço continuar rodando no boot do aparelho, ou seja com o app originador fechado.
veja aqui, em ingles, pode te ajudar com um exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496863/how-to-run-countdowntimer-in-a-service-in-android

Comment: Esse em ingles, eu to começando entender ele, ja entendi o broadcast, mas eu n entendo pq ele reinicia a contagem quando o app é deletado da memoria, parece que ele recria o service quando isso acontece, não deveria continuar rodando?

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, mas mudei de ideia, não vou ter necessidade de manter em background, então só precisa q a contagem continue daonde parou - o tempo que passou, porem estou com dificuldades em fazer o calculo de tempo, se puder me ajuda, abri outra pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/230632/como-fazer-calculo-de-tempo-no-android